# Is it correct to natural to use the verb "correct" in the sense of changing people's behavior for the better?

Tags: word-usage

Is it correct to natural to use the verb *correct* in the sense of changing people's behavior for the better? For example:

> In a lot of cases prisons don't **correct** people.

If it is not natural, what would you say instead?

Comment: I can't find an instance where the word is used like that. To me, it does not sound natural. However, you may play with it and put *correct* in quotes: *Prisons don't work; they don't "correct" people!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really correct a person, you correct a person's behavior. So it would be better to say:

> Prisons don't correct people's behavior.

"Rehabilitate" is another word for correcting people's behavior. So an even better way of expressing this thought would be to say:

> Prisons don't rehabilitate people.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is an appropriate word.
The relevant definition: 
[American Heritage Dictionary definition 2b](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=correct)

Consider related words: correctional institutions, Department of Corrections.

A related word is 'incorrigible', meaning something that can't be corrected.